# Why aren't operators documented for System.Int32?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know if this question makes much sense, but it seems confussing for me.

1. C# supports operators overloading.
2. System.Int32 is an structure. We can say it is a class with value semantics.

Why aren't operators (e.g. +, -, &, etc.) listed in System.Int32 documentation like any other methods?

Comment: They are "intrinsic" operators, part of the C# and MSIL language specification.  Like [Opcodes.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  No operator+() method is required to get the compiler and jitter to understand what is intended.  It would also be impossible to write such an operator without inducing this web site's name, System.Int32 was written in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Who told you operators aren't documented?

**Performing Operations on Int32 Values**

The Int32 type supports standard mathematical operations such as addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, negation, and unary negation. Like the other integral types, the Int32 type also supports the bitwise AND, OR, XOR, left shift, and right shift operators.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I saw this part. But why aren't they listed as any other method of the System.Int32 structure?